# How to use both database and LDAP authentication in Spring security?

Tags: database, spring-mvc, ldap, spring-security

We have a Spring MVC application. We now have to integrate spring security in it.

The authentication can be done using either database or using LDAP.

We will a have a configuration setting either in a properties file or a database to decide which authentication to use i.e. if the user should be authenticated against a database or a LDAP.

At any given time there will be only one type of authentication.

e.g. A company test1 can have a database authentication and another company test 2 can have ldap authentication.

Comment: do you already know how to authenticate with both methods separately? If don't, I suggest you go learn them first.

Comment: @bluefoot. Hi. Yeah I am currently doing that only. In the meantime if you can suggest some ways to do this, it will be really helpful to me.

Comment: Just to clarify, you are making this decision at runtime / request time? Or this is a configuration setting that will remain constant while the secured application is still running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some ideas:

1. If each client is deployed separately with its own configuration, configure the DAO and LDAP authentication in 2 different XML files.  At build time, choose which one you want to use and bundle it in your WAR.
2. If there is only 1 WAR, maybe try including both XML files in the WAR, and set a system property using `-Dmyprop=foo` (o some other way) when starting up the app.  Then, in your Spring config, include the appropriate config file using `${myprop}` so that the correct file is called and used.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I would likely go with idea 2. But could you please explain how to load a particular spring security file at runtime using the setting in property file. (I will have a property in application properties file indicating if db or ldap auth should be used.)

Comment: Are you running only 1 WAR, and both clients can hit it at runtime?