# Multiple Authentication in Java EE Application

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee, authentication, glassfish

Currently I have a requirement from a client where the user may belong to an LDAP server for authentication, or they may belong in an authentication database table.

I want to implement authorisation on my web-service methods with a two step process whereby, (a) the user is first checked against the LDAP server. If the user is not in the LDAP server then (b) check the database table for the user.

In other words it is a cascading two step process. Can this be done in any application server such as Glassfish? I've heard that JBoss can do this.

Comment: Write your custom LoginModule that checks both LDAP and database? That's my first solution that comes to mind.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it depends on the server, it has to do with whatever security mechanism you choose (like Spring Security etc). I was able to achieve this on Tomcat with Spring Security.

EDIT: you might wanna read this: [How to use both database and LDAP authentication in Spring security?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7009469/how-to-use-both-database-and-ldap-authentication-in-spring-security)